# Light Weight CMS for one pager

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

Creating a one page site want a really light weight CMS. I usually use wordpress for all my projects but seems so heavy for this project.

One page:

Bio

News Feed

Contact

I want the client to be able to edit their bio including the picture and add short news entries that populate a feed.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WordPress.

Sure it's *heavy*, but your existing knowledge of WordPress combined with meeting your requirements for a CMS outweigh that fact.

The client can always grow into the site and your future self will be thankful you didn't spring for some [fashionable solution](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/09/code-style-fashion/).

Comment: Nice article on 'Fashion vs. Style' - I wholeheartedly concur.